# Pre-generated views for multiple databases in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, view, multiple-databases

We have implemented multiple database support with `Entity Framework v1` in our application (as described in [Multiple database support with Entity Framework](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx)). We use `SQL` and `SQL Compact databases`. We used SQL db to create ou model and we have separate `ssdl` file for comapct db (**OurModel.SQLCE.ssdl**).

Everything worked fine, until we decided to use pre-generated views. If we generate views with `OurModel.ssdl`, everything works with SQL database, but it's not working with SQL CE database. We get the following exception:

> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.MappingException: The Mapping and Metadata information for EntityContainer 'OurModelEntities' no longer matches the information used to create the pre generated views.

We want to use pre-generated views for SQL and SQL CE database or `turn-off` using pre-generated views when our application is using SQl CE database.

So, my question is: Is thera a way to use pre-generated views when using multiple databases in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this applies to your issue. But I ve got the same error message and I realized that was due to that, I have done a change in one of a model classes but haven't added a migration for it.

So what I did was,

in the package manager console i gave below command

```
add-migration "Migration###"
```

then ran the `update-database` command

and that did the trick.